# MySQL LEFT JOIN ON/WHERE

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am joining my address book onto my email table like this:

```
SELECT * FROM messages m
LEFT JOIN addr_book a ON 
m.to_msg LIKE a.h_email 
OR m.to_msg LIKE a.bill_email 
OR m.to_msg LIKE a.b_email 
OR m.to_msg LIKE a.w_email 
OR m.to_msg LIKE a.other_email 
OR m.from_msg LIKE a.h_email 
OR m.from_msg LIKE a.bill_email 
OR m.from_msg LIKE a.b_email 
OR m.from_msg LIKE a.w_email 
OR m.from_msg LIKE a.other_email 
OR m.cc_msg LIKE a.h_email 
OR m.cc_msg LIKE a.bill_email 
OR m.cc_msg LIKE a.b_email 
OR m.cc_msg LIKE a.w_email 
OR m.cc_msg LIKE a.other_email 
OR m.bcc_msg LIKE a.h_email 
OR m.bcc_msg LIKE a.bill_email 
OR m.bcc_msg LIKE a.b_email 
OR m.bcc_msg LIKE a.w_email 
OR m.bcc_msg LIKE a.other_email
```

The problem is it fetches everything, because some contacts don't have emails and join up with emails that don't have cc_msg='' or bcc_msg=''

Is there a way I can left join a table on a column where the column is like '@'??

I tried a couple things like `IN (m.to_message LIKE a.h_email WHERE a.h_email LIKE '%@%') OR` etc etc

But I keep getting errors.

Any ideas?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Why are you using `a LIKE b` instead of `a = b`?

Comment: because some users save the email with caps in it (like MrJones@gmail.com) and the messages table only contains lowercase.

Comment: You need to read about [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_%28database%29). Instead of having a wide row with multiple columns for different types of email address, you should have a separate table containing the user id, address type, and address. Then you could easily join (and search) the email addresses for a match.

Comment: LIKE doesn't make things case-insensitive in MySQL, does it? It doesn't in any other DBMS I've ever seen.

Comment: You know you get case-insensitive comparisons in MySQL by default, right? That is, unless you choose a binary collation. You shouldn't resort to `LIKE` just to get case insensitivity. Your query is unindexable and will become very very slow as soon as the quantity of data increases. And +1 to what Ken said.

Comment: Oh snap.. = is NOT case sensitive in mySQL. Im dumb.

Comment: @bobince, I know your comment was addressed to Ryan, but *I* didn't know MySQL was case-insensitive by default (I've never used MySQL). Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Ken: yeah, it's not always a nice surprise, either—you can come up with some nasty scenarios where your code's idea of string equality differing from MySQL's idea of equality leads to unexpected (or potentially dangerous) results. When they need to match, you generally want a binary collation. (There are various other case-sensitive collations too, which may make sense for some particular languages/circumstances.)

Comment: @bobince: I would agree 100%. There could be some real problems. I prefer case-sensitivity for the most part, at least for the types of things I generally do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so that helps out alot. I don't know why, but I have always assumed = is case sensitive in mySQL. I used the following and it works beautifully. Thanks all, I'm sure if I had proper training I wouldn't have made this mistake in the first place lol.

```
LEFT JOIN addr_book a ON 

(m.to_msg=a.h_email OR m.to_msg=a.bill_email OR m.to_msg=a.b_email OR m.to_msg=a.w_email OR m.to_msg=a.other_email) OR

(m.from_msg=a.h_email OR m.from_msg=a.bill_email OR m.from_msg=a.b_email OR m.from_msg=a.w_email OR m.from_msg=a.other_email) OR

((m.cc_msg!='') AND (m.cc_msg=a.h_email OR m.cc_msg=a.bill_email OR m.cc_msg=a.b_email OR m.cc_msg=a.w_email OR m.cc_msg=a.other_email)) OR 

((m.bcc_msg!='') AND (m.bcc_msg=a.h_email OR m.bcc_msg=a.bill_email OR m.bcc_msg=a.b_email OR m.bcc_msg=a.w_email OR m.bcc_msg=a.other_email))
```

Comment: for case sensitivity, you can use LOWER or LCASE or some such thing.

Comment: please learn how to format SQL or code. You can use the button on the editor (looks like a square box with circles in it), indent each line by four spaces, or select all of the code/SQL and then use Ctrl+Shift+K. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you need to use AND instead of WHERE:

```
ON (m.to_message LIKE a.h_email AND a.h_email LIKE '%@%') OR (...
```

I think you might mean `=` instead of LIKE for the first test, which would give this:

```
ON (m.to_message = a.h_email AND a.h_email LIKE '%@%') OR (...
```

Or perhaps you just need this:

```
ON m.to_message = a.h_email
```

Unlike LIKE, an equality test will fail if `a.h_email` is empty but `m.to_message` is non-empty.

Comment: But equality will fail if the address book email has any caps in it. The messages table only has lowercase but the address book may have uppercase if the user chooses. And I want to avoid loading the contact and forcing the emails to lower before querying.

Comment: Ok, so = is def NOT case sensitive as I assumed.. I will try what you have above..